# Cannot change PlivoLoginAppDelegate to swift in iOS SDK

Tags: plivo

In your iOS SDK PlivoLogin, there are PlivoLoginAppDelegate.h and PlivoLoginAppDelegate.m.
I want to change it to swift file.
I changed it to the following.

```html
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

 class var shared: AppDelegate {
 return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 }
 
 var providerDelegate: ProviderDelegate?
 
 var window: UIWindow?
 @IBOutlet var viewController: ViewController?
 var phone: Phone?
 
 // MARK: UIApplicationDelegate
 
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
 print("Finished launching with options: \(launchOptions)")
 
// // Phone
 self.phone = Phone()
 self.viewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController
 self.viewController?.phone = self.phone
 self.phone?.setDelegate(self.viewController)
 
 
 return true
 }
 ...
}
```

But the log only says

- Creating endpoint
- Generating random password

and stops, fails to get a delegate response to - (void)successWithResponse:.
How can we get a delegate response?

Answer (score 0):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

Plivo iOS SDK has Objective C interface and you can access the Objective-C library from the Swift 3.0. [This](https://github.com/shaileshplivo/iOS) is a sample app in the Swift 3.0 using the iOS SDK's Objective-C interface. This app makes outgoing calls and gets delegate callbacks in Swift 3.0.